# can we create or get exception when data is not saved in database using sugar orm

Tags: android, sugarorm

I made an application where i will save data using sugar orm !! i have given the application to others and they complain that in very rare case the data doesn't gets saved in database !! so i want to know if its possible and if yes than how can i make the user to know that the data is not saved or simply how to handle it !!

```
Data data = new Data();


String datasn = getResources().getString(R.string.data_code);

costdisplay();

datasn = datasn + DateTime.now().toString("ddMMyyHHmmss");
datasn = datasn + vehicleNumber;
data.setsn(datasn);
data.sT(dataType);
data.setEvent(DateTime.now().toString("dd/MM/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
Log.e("data", DateTime.now().toString("dd/MM/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
data.setRNumber(vehicleNumber);
data.setIsSync(false);
data.setConsider(true);
data.setType(priceType);
data.setMessage(messageForPostpaid);
Log.e("log", data.getType());
data.setEventType(VehicleStatus.CHECKED_IN);
data.setCost(cost);
data.save();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Few questions: Are You able to reproduce issue? Query log is avaiable - nothing is logged there? Is the thread that  does the save interrupted? Any exception is thrown? Its first time I hear about that kind of problem for SugarORM, but maybe an override of save method with some kind of check after save would be enough to validate?

Comment: the app is tested in live environment and the users are non technical !! so cant get any help from them and i personally don't face such issue . can you suggest me what kind of check ???

Comment: Just do query for Your item after save like `public void save(){ super.save();
boolean savedStatus = Data.find(Data.class,"where_example_extra_id_or similar",values...).size()!=0;}`